# How to retrieve multiple data from firebase to List View in android?

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

i want to retrieve all this data to ListView in android studio, is that possible ?
It´s easy to do ? I´m new in code develop.

[![Firebase Data][1]][1]

I'm using "addValueEventListener" for retrieve the data:

```
reff2 = database.getInstance().getReference().child("Registo Inicial e Final");

reff2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Log.e("MATRICULAA", String.valueOf(ds.child("matricula").getValue()));


               String message = ds.child("nome_CONDUTOR").getValue().toString();
               String message2 = ds.child("matricula").getValue().toString();
               String message3 = ds.child("cod_PROJETO").getValue().toString();
               String message4 = ds.child("km_INICIAL").getValue().toString();
               String message5 = ds.child("km_FINAL").getValue().toString();
               String message6 = ds.child("data_INICIO").getValue().toString();
               String message7 = ds.child("data_FIM").getValue().toString();
               String message8 = ds.child("hora_INICIO").getValue().toString();
               String message9 = ds.child("hora_FIM").getValue().toString();
               String message10 = ds.child("observacoes").getValue().toString();

               Log.e("KM", String.valueOf(ds.child("km_FINAL").getValue()));

               Nome.setText(message);
               Matricula.setText(message2);
               Cod.setText(message3);
               Kilometros_inicial.setText(message4);
               Kilometros_final.setText(message5);
               Data_inicial.setText(message6);
               Data_final.setText(message7);
               Hora_inicial.setText(message8);
               Hora_final.setText(message9);
               Observacoes.setText(message10);
           }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        
        Log.e("The read failed: " ,databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

This is what i get:
I want all the data from diferent nodes,i dont know why its overwriting the data..

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: It would really be helpful if you could point out what in your code is working and what isn't working, what error message do you get?

Comment: The data retrieved is overwriting, it only show all the data from the last "Random firebase push key"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can.Its pretty easy. Create a class like this:

```
public class YourClass(){
    public String cod_PROJETO;
    public String data_FIM; 
    .... /// All or required data items here


    // no argument constructor
    public YourClass(){}


    public String getCod_PROJETO(){
        return cod_PROJETO;
    }

    public void setCod_PROJETO(String cod_PROJETO){
        this.cod_PROJETO = cod_PROJETO;
    }
    .... /// Getters and setters for your data items.
    .... /// Android studio code completion suggestions will make this easier;
}
```

Remember: if you are using getter and setter, they must be public, else the variable must be public. Using getter and setter is preferred method.

Then your this class in your valueEvent listener like this:

```
YourClass data = ds.getValue(YourClass.class);
```

Since you want to show it in ListView, use something like this in your valueEventListener:

```
yourClassList.clear();
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    YourClass data = ds.getValue(YourClass.class);
    if(data != null)
        yourClassList.add(data);
}
// update your listView adapter here using notifyDataSetChanged
```

By this way, you can also set data in firebase like:

```
myRef.child("key").setValue(data);  //data = object of class YourClass
```